# How can I replace default thread pool in Dispatch?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

How can I replace default thread pool in Dispatch ? I see here https://github.com/dispatch/dispatch/blob/master/futures/src/main/scala/Futures.scala that instantiates CachedThreadPool. I'd like to use FixedThreadPool instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorry for being lazy, guys. Quick look at sources of Dispatch showed that I can pass my thread executor via `setExecutorService` of `Http.configure`.

For example

```
val pool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val httpClient: Http = Http.configure(_.setAllowPoolingConnection(true).setFollowRedirects(true).setConnectionTimeoutInMs(1000).setExecutorService(pool))
```

Comment: The only problem is that it didn't work. Dispatch doesn't use object that I passed :( I'll post updates later.